# Jenkins pipeline script path

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

After setting up the GitHub path in the Jenkins pipeline definition SCM (using GitHub webhook), can set the Jenkinsfile script path below to be in another repository on GitHub?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmM9t.png)

Thanks.

For example:

Webhook repository (https://github.example.com/example/test.git

Jenkinsfile repository (https://github.example.com/jenkinsfile/jenkinsfile-test.git)

Answer (score 0):

to get the Jenkinsfile from repo as the Jenkinsfile of another one (based on what I understood)

you can use a plugin in it called [`remote jenkins provider`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/)